# If x =-1 for the derivative of ln(x)=1/x does that imply that ln(-1) = -1?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, logarithms

I wanted to find the solution of x for y=ln(x)-1/x=0 and my first intuition was to rearrange the equation to ln(x)=1/x and find the first derivative of the equation which gave me 1/x=-x^-2. I rearranged this equation to get x and it got me to x=-1. this made me ask if x=-1, does that imply that ln(-1)=-1? I understand that there are other ways to find x which is true for the equation. but I don't understand why this doesn't work and why ln(-1) is not equal to -1 even when x=-1. Does anybody have any ideas as to why this is?

Comment: The derivative of $\ln(x)$ is not defined for $x<0$ because $\ln(x)$ is not defined for $x<0.$ Anyway, the derivative of $\ln|x|$ is $1/x$, not $\ln x.$ Just because you can do substitutions doesn’t make it true. (If you were dealing with complex multivalued natural logarithm, there would be some truth to it, but not the real logarithm.)

Comment: Also, if $f’(x_0)=g’(x_0)$ means nothing about whether $f(x_0)=g(x_0).$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's where your argument is not valid.

When we solve an equation of the forme
$$f(x)=g(x)\text{ at } \Bbb R$$
this doesn't mean that the equality above is satisfied for all reals $ x $.

So, as you did, we cannot differentiate to get
$$f'(x)=g'(x)$$
As a counterexample, the equation
$$x^2=4$$
becomes
$$2x=0$$
which is an other equation.

Answer (score 2):

The solution to $\ln x =\frac1x$ can be written as $$x\ln x =\ln(x^x)=1,$$
or $x^x=e.$ There must be a solution $1<x<2,$ since $x^x$ is increasing for $x>1$ and $1^1<e<2^2.$

There are no other real solutions, because when $0<x\leq 1,$ $x^x\leq 1,$ and $\ln x$ is not defined for $x\leq 0.$

If $y=\ln x$ then the equation becomes $x\ln x =ye^y=1,$ which means we can write the answer as $y=W(1)$ where $W$ is the [Lambert W-function.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function?wprov=sfti1) Then $x=e^y=e^{W(1)}.$

It is unclear why taking the derivative helps you at all solve this question. In general, $f’(x_0)=g’(x_0)$ doesn’t help you solve $f(x)=g(x).$

Derivatives of a function are only defined where the function is defined. Anyway, the “anti-derivative” of $\frac1x$ is $\ln|x|,$ not $\ln x,$ when $x<0.$